# absolute value of sum of complex numbers squared

Tags: complex-numbers

is this correct

$ \left| |a| \exp(-i c)-|b| \exp(-i d) \right|^2=|a|^2-2|a||b|+|b|^2$

Thank you

Comment: The left hand side depends on $c$ and $d$, the right hand side doesn't. So it's not correct. Something on the right must depend on $c$ and $d$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, there *could* be some cancellations... but yes, here the LHS does depend on $c-d$.

Comment: OP: Did you try to plug $c=0$, $d=\pi$ in the LHS?

Comment: @Did And if $c$ and $d$ need not be real, not only on $c-d$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, although I suspect that the OP means c and d to be real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left| |a| \exp(-i c)-|b| \exp(-i d) \right|^2=(|a| \exp(-i c)-|b| \exp(-i d) )\times( |a| \exp(i c)-|b| \exp(i d))$$
so
$$\left| |a| \exp(-i c)-|b| \exp(-i d) \right|^2=|a|^2-(\exp(i (c-d))+\exp(i (d-c))|a||b| +|b|^2$$
so
$$\left| |a| \exp(-i c)-|b| \exp(-i d) \right|^2=|a|^2-2\cos(c-d)|a||b| +|b|^2$$

Comment: Thank you. What would be a nice lower bound on this expression not involving any imaginary numbers???

Comment: I added a third line, the lower bound is reached maximizing the cosine, so $min = |a|^2-2|a||b|+|b|^2$

Comment: @user63050, my pleasure ;)